# Communicating between two different computers with TCP/IP

Tags: java, sockets, ip, client, server

I've been studying how to use sockets to make two java programs communicate.

Now, on each example I've gone through, they've always placed the "server side program" on the same computer on which the "client side program" was, and of course the IP set was either 127.0.0.1 , or simply "localhost".

Now, my question is: 
**how do I get to communicate the two programs if one is on a computer, and one on another?**

I've tried to set the IP as the one my computer has when connected to internet (the one I found simply by googling "what's my IP"), but that way it doesn't seems to work.
 Can anyone explain me better how I can make it work?

Comment: Yeah, I know, my networking knowledge is not the best. I actually haven't take that class yet. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to figure it out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The computers will need to be on the same network or their IP address will need to be accessible to the internet. If you are in windows, you can find the local IP address by opening a cmd window (press windows key + R then type cmd) and running ipconfig. On linux (maybe it works on Mac as well) you can run ifconfig in a terminal. If your computers are on the same local area network you should be able to use the IP addresses indicated by those commands.

If they are not on the same local area network, a router in between the computers may have a firewall policy which is blocking the connection.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've been told this already, but this is what I don't get: they say that I have to put the server program on the server I want it to run on. But, since I don't host a server in my house and my only way to do it is to buy an external server, how do I start the program on that external server? Since I'll probably be able to connect to it just by FTP.

Comment: @Sinth92 you don't need a physical server. That's why I told you to review Networking 101. It's half joke half truth: on a network, you could have a bridge or a router and two pcs connected to this component using a cross cable, then the two pcs are in a LAN, and one of them may work as a server and the other as a client. You don't need to buy an external server on the net or something similar, you can use a single PC for this by using a virtual machine. And again, please review some of Networking on the net, otherwise I recommend you to not get involved in network programming **yet**.

Comment: Start by running your server app and client app on the **same machine**, get the communication working using `127.0.0.1`, THEN move them to separate machines and update the IP used for connecting.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I understand what you're saying, but what I'm trying to do is to create a server application I can communicate to from the internet, not on a LAN.

Comment: @Sinth92 then you have two issues: 1) the description of your problem **doesn't indicate that purpose**: *how do I get to communicate the two programs if one is on a computer, and one on another?* 2) you're using the wrong approach. Do some research on web services or peer to peer (P2P). Explain your real purposes to communicate two pcs across internet and you will get more accurate guidance

Comment: @Sinth92 - Presumably the reason why what you tried (according to your question) didn't work is exactly what Aaryn Tonita wrote at the end of his answer: _a router in between the computers may have a firewall policy which is blocking the connection._ So you'd have to look into your router.