# Java Socket programming - implementing on local PC and VM

Tags: java, sockets

I have learnt server-client side socket programming by watching/browsing tutorials. However, in all these tutorials, the server and client side are implemented on the same machine.

As a follow up to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403964/communicating-between-two-different-computers-with-tcp-ip) if I try to set up a connection between my local PC and a VM (both on the same subnet),

1. How would I run the server side socket on the VM?
2. Would I have to have an IDE in the VM and run the server side code there, and at the same time run the client side code on my local PC?

How can this be extrapolated to multiple systems?

Comment: you need to execute the server program on one machine (VM) its depend on the  language you used you can use executable file or set all IDE setup and run on the VM

After that you can run your client machine to connect to Vm with Vm Ipaddress and the listening port

Comment: If im using java, on the local pc, i can set the same port and the IP of the VM, where as when I run the IDE for server side on the VM, I have to set the same port and also the IP of the local PC. Is this what you are saying?